# Переопределение pure virtual метода базового класс для определённого типа в классе наследнике С++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, virtual, override

Имеется базовый класс с чисто виртуальным методом

```
template <class Key, class Value>
class AbstractContainer {
 public:
  virtual ~AbstractContainer() = 0;
  virtual const std::size_t Upload(std::ifstream &is) = 0;
};
```

Он наследуется для следующего класса.

```
template <class Key, class Value>
class HashTable : virtual public AbstractContainer<Key, Value> {
 public:
  HashTable();
  ~HashTable();

  virtual const std::size_t Upload(std::ifstream &is) override final;
};
```

А метод переопределяется следующим образом.

```
template <class Key, class Value>
HashTable<Key, Value>::~HashTable() {}

template <>
const std::size_t HashTable<std::string, Storage>::Upload(std::ifstream &is) {
  std::size_t loaded{0};

  Storage storage;
  std::istringstream stream;
  static const std::regex regex(R"(^\w{1,15}\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\d{4}\s+\S+\s+\d+(\s+)?$)");
  for(std::string line, key; std::getline(is, line); stream.clear()) {
    if (stream.str(line), std::regex_match(line, regex)) {
      stream >> key;
      stream >> storage;
      loaded += Set(key, storage);
    }
  }
  return loaded;
}
```

Как переопределить метод на следующие типы, оставив в базовом класе метод чисто виртуальным и при этом избавиться от ошибки?

```
[build] duplicate symbol 'virtual thunk to HashTable<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, Storage>::Upload(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)' in:
[build]     CMakeFiles/Transaction.dir/interface/interface.cc.o
[build]     CMakeFiles/Transaction.dir/main.cc.o
[build] duplicate symbol 'HashTable<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, Storage>::Upload(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)' in:
[build]     CMakeFiles/Transaction.dir/interface/interface.cc.o
[build]     CMakeFiles/Transaction.dir/main.cc.o
```

hash_table.h

```
#ifndef TRANSACTION_SRC_TABLE_HASH_TABLE_H_
#define TRANSACTION_SRC_TABLE_HASH_TABLE_H_

#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <regex>

#include "container.h"
#include "storage.h"

template <class Key, class Value>
class HashTable : virtual public AbstractContainer<Key, Value> {
 public:
  HashTable();
  HashTable(HashTable &other);
  HashTable(HashTable &&other);
  ~HashTable();

  virtual const bool Set(const Key &key, const Value &value) override final;
  [[nodiscard]] virtual std::optional<Value> Get(const Key &key) override final;
  [[nodiscard]] virtual const bool Exists(const Key &key) override final;
  virtual const bool Del(const Key &key) override final;
  virtual const bool Update(const Key &key, const Value &value) override final;
  [[nodiscard]] virtual std::vector<Key> Keys() override final;
  virtual const bool Rename(const Key &key, const Key &rename) override final;
  [[nodiscard]] virtual const std::optional<std::size_t> TTL(const Key &key) override final;
  [[nodiscard]] virtual std::vector<Key> Find(const Value &value) override final;
  virtual void Showall() override final;
  // virtual const std::size_t Upload(std::ifstream &is) override final;
  // virtual const std::size_t Export(std::ofstream &os) override final;

  HashTable &operator=(HashTable &other);
  HashTable &operator=(HashTable &&other);

 private:
  std::size_t m_mpn_cur_idx;
  static const std::vector<std::size_t> m_mpn;

  std::vector<std::list<std::shared_ptr<std::pair<Key, Value> > > > m_data;

  void ResizeHashTable();
  [[nodiscard]] std::tuple<typename std::list<std::shared_ptr<std::pair<Key, Value> > >::iterator, std::size_t> GetListIteratorByKey(const Key &key);
};

#include "hash_table.tpp"

#endif  // TRANSACTION_SRC_TABLE_HASH_TABLE_H_
```

hash_table.tpp

```
template <class Key, class Value>
const std::vector<std::size_t> HashTable<Key, Value>::m_mpn{
    3,
    7,
    31,
    127,
    8'191,
    131'071,
    524'287,
    2'147'483'647,
    2'305'843'009'213'693'951,
    std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()};

template <class Key, class Value>
HashTable<Key, Value>::HashTable() : m_mpn_cur_idx{0} {
  m_data.resize(m_mpn[m_mpn_cur_idx]);
}

template <class Key, class Value>
HashTable<Key, Value>::HashTable(HashTable &other) {
  *this = other;
}

template <class Key, class Value>
HashTable<Key, Value>::HashTable(HashTable &&other) {
  *this = other;
}

template <class Key, class Value>
HashTable<Key, Value>::~HashTable() {}

template <class Key, class Value>
[[nodiscard]] std::tuple<typename std::list<std::shared_ptr<std::pair<Key, Value> > >::iterator, std::size_t> HashTable<Key, Value>::GetListIteratorByKey(const Key &key) {
  std::size_t idx = std::hash<Key>{}(key) % m_mpn[m_mpn_cur_idx];
  auto item = std::find_if(m_data[idx].begin(), m_data[idx].end(), [&](const std::shared_ptr<std::pair<Key, Value> > &pair) {
    return pair->first == key;
  });

  return std::make_tuple(item, idx);
}

template <class Key, class Value>
const bool HashTable<Key, Value>::Set(const Key &key, const Value &value) {
  auto [item, idx] = GetListIteratorByKey(key);

  bool seted{m_data[idx].end() == item};
  if (seted) {
    m_data[idx].push_back(std::make_shared<std::pair<Key, Value> >(key, value));
    if (++this->m_amount_elements == m_mpn[m_mpn_cur_idx]) {
      ResizeHashTable();
    }
  }
  return seted;
}

template <class Key, class Value>
void HashTable<Key, Value>::ResizeHashTable() {
  decltype(m_data) temp(m_mpn[++m_mpn_cur_idx]);
  for (auto &list: m_data) {
    for (auto &pair: list) {
      std::size_t idx = std::hash<Key>{}(pair->first) % m_mpn[m_mpn_cur_idx];
      temp[idx].push_back(pair);
    }
  }
  m_data = std::move(temp);
}

template <class Key, class Value>
[[nodiscard]] std::optional<Value> HashTable<Key, Value>::Get(const Key &key) {
  auto [item, idx] = GetListIteratorByKey(key);

  std::optional<Value> result;
  if (m_data[idx].end() != item) {
    result = (*item)->second;
  }
  return result;
}

template <class Key, class Value>
[[nodiscard]] const bool HashTable<Key, Value>::Exists(const Key &key) {
  auto [item, idx] = GetListIteratorByKey(key);
  return m_data[idx].end() != item;
}

template <class Key, class Value>
const bool HashTable<Key, Value>::Del(const Key &key) {
  auto [item, idx] = GetListIteratorByKey(key);

  bool deleted{m_data[idx].end() != item};
  if (--this->m_amount_elements, deleted) {
    m_data[idx].erase(item);
  }
  return deleted;
}

template <class Key, class Value>
const bool HashTable<Key, Value>::Update(const Key &key, const Value &value) {
  auto [item, idx] = GetListIteratorByKey(key);

  bool updated{m_data[idx].end() != item};
  if (updated) {
    (*item)->second = value;
  }
  return updated;
}

template <class Key, class Value>
[[nodiscard]] std::vector<Key> HashTable<Key, Value>::Keys() {
  std::vector<Key> result;
  for (auto &list: m_data) {
    for (auto &item: list) {
      result.push_back(item->first);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

template <class Key, class Value>
const bool HashTable<Key, Value>::Rename(const Key &key, const Key &rename) {
  auto [item, idx] = GetListIteratorByKey(key);

  bool renamed{m_data[idx].end() != item};
  if (renamed) {
    (*item)->first = rename;
  }
  return renamed;
}

template <class Key, class Value>
[[nodiscard]] const std::optional<std::size_t> HashTable<Key, Value>::TTL(const Key &key) {
  auto [item, idx] = GetListIteratorByKey(key);

  std::optional<std::size_t> seconds;
  if (m_data[idx].end() != item && (*item)->second.GetRemovalTime().has_value()) {
    auto time_1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto time_2 = (*item)->second.GetRemovalTime().value();
    seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(time_2 - time_1).count();
  }
  return seconds;
}

template <class Key, class Value>
std::vector<Key> HashTable<Key, Value>::Find(const Value &value) {
  std::vector<Key> result;
  for (auto &list: m_data) {
    for (auto &item: list) {
      if (item->second == value) {
        result.push_back(item->first);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

template <class Key, class Value>
void HashTable<Key, Value>::Showall() {
  std::size_t iteration{1};
  for (auto &list: m_data) {
    for (auto &item: list) {
      std::cout << "> " << iteration++ << " ";
      std::cout << item->second << "\n";
    }
  }
}

// template <>
// const std::size_t HashTable<std::string, Storage>::Upload(std::ifstream &is) {
//   std::size_t loaded{0};

//   Storage storage;
//   std::istringstream stream;
//   static const std::regex regex(R"(^\w{1,15}\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\d{4}\s+\S+\s+\d+(\s+)?$)");
//   for(std::string line, key; std::getline(is, line); stream.clear()) {
//     if (stream.str(line), std::regex_match(line, regex)) {
//       stream >> key;
//       stream >> storage;
//       loaded += Set(key, storage);
//     }
//   }
//   return loaded;
// }

// template <>
// const std::size_t HashTable<std::string, Storage>::Export(std::ofstream &os) {
//   std::size_t unloaded{0};
//   for (auto &list: m_data) {
//     for (auto &item: list) {
//       os << item->first << " " << item->second;
//       if (++unloaded != this->m_amount_elements) {
//         os << '\n';
//       }
//     }
//   }
//   return unloaded;
// }

template <class Key, class Value>
HashTable<Key, Value> &HashTable<Key, Value>::operator=(HashTable &other) {
  if (this != &other) {
    m_data.clear();
    m_data.resize(m_mpn[m_mpn_cur_idx = {}]);
    this->m_amount_elements = {};
    for (auto &list: other.m_data) {
      for (auto &item: list) {
        Set(item->first, item->second);
      }
    }
  }
  return *this;
}

template <class Key, class Value>
HashTable<Key, Value> &HashTable<Key, Value>::operator=(HashTable &&other) {
  if (this != &other) {
    this->m_amount_elements = {};
    m_mpn_cur_idx = other.m_mpn_cur_idx;
    m_data = std::move(other.m_data);
    other.m_mpn_cur_idx = {};
    other.m_amount_elements = {};
  }
  return *this;
}
```

container.tpp

```
template <class Key, class Value>
AbstractContainer<Key, Value>::~AbstractContainer() {}

template <class Key, class Value>
[[nodiscard]] const std::size_t AbstractContainer<Key, Value>::GetAmountElements() const {
  return m_amount_elements;
}
```

Comment: А как вы собираетесь жить с отсутствующим деструктором? или удаления объектов `HashTable` не предвидится?

Comment: @Harry.        Деструктор описан

Comment: @Harry.        Обновил вопрос

Comment: Он описан, но тела `~AbstractContainer()` нет. Что будет вызываться при удалении `HashTable`?

Comment: И базовый класс `class AbstractContainer` абстрактный. Зачем его вообще шаблоном делать - теряется весь смысл? Если он шаблон, значит их будет много, в зависимости от типов шаблона. А нужен-то по-идее один базовый класс для разных `class HashTable<>`.

Comment: @Harry.               template <class Key, class Value>
AbstractContainer<Key, Value>::~AbstractContainer() {}

Comment: @DmitryK.      Шаблонный потому-что может быть много различных вариаций, на данный момент использую только одну в рамках изучения

Comment: Обычно, абстрактный базовый класс нужен один, а не много. А вот у наследников - много вариаций. Иначе смысл теряется.

Comment: Возможно, но нигде в приведенном тексте его нет. Не доверяя глазам, даже выполнил поиск `~AbstractContainer` браузером :)

Comment: @Harry.        Описал в .cc файле скомпилилось, tpp - я так понимаю там переопределять не следовало?